# TCPDF - check if the saving PDF file was finished

Tags: save, output, tcpdf

I need save DPF file, generated by TCDPF and after the saving this file I need to send information about it to another script. 
How to check if the saving PDF file to folder was finished ?

```
$pdf->Output('folder/example_006.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... What about something like this:

```php
$pdf->Output('folder/example_006.pdf', 'F');
if(file_exists('folder/example_006.pdf')){
    //success;
} else {
    //fail;
}
```

?

Comment: It is not so clear solution, but it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I want to send a response only after the file is saved. when i check file_exist(), it always returns false.

Comment: @Annapurna are you shure that file is exist, and you use correct filename/path for check?

Answer (score 1):

Its expected that if TCPDF throws catchable error if cannot write output to file. But I guess this may not be sufficient for you. So I have added second check if file exists in the expected folder. 
But this check only regular check doesn't guarantee any pdf error. 
Lets see the code :

```php
$filePath = 'folder/example_006.pdf';
try{
    $pdf->Output($filePath, 'F');
} catch(Exception $ex){
    return false;
}

return file_exists($filePath);
```

Please do not hesistate to ask anything. 
Hope Works !!!